# MVC Pass object through view by view name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, view, html.dropdownlistfor

When calling this method below, everything works as expected`

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            ViewBag.ReplyList = new BusinessLayer.Telesales().getAllReplies();
            //ViewBag.AssignTo = new BusinessLayer.Users().getUsersByRoleName("Sales Rep");

            CommonLayer.Telesales telesale = new BusinessLayer.Telesales().getTelesale(id);
            return View(telesale);
        }
```

However, after updating the database below, I try to recall the same view and pass the same parameters as in the previous method. For some reason when the method below calls the View, I get a `NullReferenceException` error on the dropdownlist being populated from the ViewBag

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CommonLayer.Telesales telesale)
        {
            ViewBag.ReplyList = new BusinessLayer.Telesales().getAllReplies();

            if (telesale.Reply != 1)
            { 
                new BusinessLayer.Telesales().updateTelesale(telesale,User.Identity.Name);
                //Appointment
                if (telesale.Reply == 6)
                {
                    ViewBag.Appointment = true;
                    ViewBag.ReplyList = new BusinessLayer.Telesales().getAllReplies();
                    return View("Edit", (object)telesale);
                    }
}
```

The view expects and object `@model CommonLayer.Telesales`

`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
on the following line inside my view:

```
   Line 53:       <div>
Line 54:             @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Reply, new SelectList(ViewBag.ReplyList, "ID", "Reply", Model.TelesalesReplies.ID), new { style = "height:31px;width:312px;" })
Line 55:             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reply)
Line 56:         </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that ViewBag.ReplyList has the expected value after being set? Otherwise, is there already a Key called "ReplyList" in your modelstate (as this value will be used by the binder over the newly assigned value)? And finally, is Model.TelesalesReplies null?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the "return" line and verify that your model "telesale" has the correct data.  Also, verify that your ViewBag contains data.  And you shouldn't need to cast your model as (object) so long as your view is expecting the model object you are passing to it.  And since your Action name is the same as the view you are returning, you don't need to specify it again.  Simply: return View(telesale);

Comment: Why are you casting `telesale` to `object` when returning? That might be your issue right there.

Comment: @Eckert You're right. For some reason the viewbag value is null. Why does it work on the first method and null on the second if it's calling the same method?

Comment: what happens if you exclude the "new" and just let it be ViewBag.ReplyList = BusinessLayer.Telesales().getAllReplies(); ?

Comment: @Eckert The problem seems to be from the Object TelesalesReplies. The first method returns a valid TelesalesReplies object (within the 'telesale' model)  and it is displayed in the view. However, when submitting the form, the TelesalesReplies object passed to the second method (HttpPost) is being return as null for some reason. I can display the TelesalesReplies object successfully in the view, but for some reason it is always being passed as 'null' to the second method [HttpPost]

Comment: Do the values you are posting match the expected model Telesale?  Perhaps you should post the Telesale model and also your post method (your form or other post-based submission method).